# Powershell get date from log file

Tags: powershell

I would like to get date from the log file text.

Text in log file.

Error code. 200105. Simple text and so on  ------------->   it should get date as 2020 Jan 05

Error code. 2000207. Simple text and so on ------------->   it should get date as 2020 Feb 07

I try this but it doesnt work.

Get-Date "200105" -format "y-m-d" but it doesnt work.

I also try "200105" | Date but still same issue

This does work [datetime]::ParseExact("120105", "y.m.d", $null) but how do I get just the date but ignore all of the other text

Comment: You can do `[datetime]::ParseExact('200105','yMMdd',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture).ToString('yyyy MMM dd')`.

Comment: I get following error when running this command.Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:7 char:1
+ [datetime]::ParseExact($text,'yMMdd',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: What is in `$text`

Comment: This work for me.$text2=[regex]::Matches($text, '\d\d+.\d\d+.\d\d')[0].Groups[0].Value

[datetime]::ParseExact($text2, "y.M.d", $null)

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7#parameters), Get-Date converts a string to a date if it recognises the date format from the locale settings.

For instance, in UK it recognises Get-Date "2020/03/21" but not Get-Date "20200321"

The format string is only used for formatting the current date.

This works: the number of characters in the format string represents the size of the input (it matches the number of digits in the day and year - it is more complicated for months) and M represents months (m represents minutes).

```
PS /home/alistair> [datetime]::ParseExact("200321","yyMMdd",$null)
```

Saturday, 21 March 2020 00:00:00

Comment: I know the format for date will always be Ymd so I do i convert that into date. $text = "some.test.12.01.05.xxx.sdsdsd"

#[datetime]::ParseExact($text, "y.m.d", $null)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shorter version you can do that by piping the output as follows

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($text2, "y.M.d", $null)

$date | Get-Date -Format dd-MMMM-yyyy
```

Or

```
$date.ToString("yyyy MMMM dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example `2000207` is invalid because of the extra `0` in there.

I would use the `TryParseExact` method here to see if what you have got is actually a parsable datetime string.

```
$logLine = 'Error code. 200105. Simple text and so on'
if ($logLine -match '^Error code\s*\.?\s*(\d{6})') {
    $date = Get-Date    # any valid DateTime object will do
    if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($Matches[1], 'yyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, 0, [ref]$date)) { 
        # do something with the date found. For demo, just output in the console
        "Found a date: $date" 
    }
}
```

You are probably reading the log file line-by-line, something like:

```
Get-Content -Path 'TheLogFile' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^Error code\s*\.?\s*(\d{6})') {
        $date = Get-Date    # any valid DateTime object will do
        if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($Matches[1], 'yyMMdd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, 0, [ref]$date)) { 
            # do something with the date found. For demo, just output in the console
            "Found a date: $date" 
        }
    }
}
```